# fs module fails when integrating Electron into Angular project

Tags: angular, electron, angular-cli, webpack-2

I have some trouble integrating Electron. When I use it as described in [this blog post](http://www.blog.bdauria.com/?p=806), everything works. Problems start when I want to use import Electron (electron.remote) to use it in Angular2 service to let the app using the desktop features like system dialogs and file system access.

I get the following error when loading the app, in **electron/index.js** which is included in webpack bundle:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function (index.js:6)
```

The file looks quite simple:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt')

if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
module.exports = path.join(__dirname, fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8'))
} else {
throw new Error('Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/' + path.basename(__dirname) + ' and try installing again')
}

//////////////////
// WEBPACK FOOTER
// ./~/electron/index.js
// module id = 609
// module chunks = 2
```

The funny thing here is that another built-in module **path** has no problem in the same piece of code. When I look in electron app's dev tools I can see the expected `path` methods as well as the two static properties (delimiters). But when I look what is the `fs` object I can see it is just an empty `Object` with the prototype corresponding with NodeJS 6.

I import the electron API in an Angular service file service.ts which is very trivial:

```
import * as electron from 'electron' ;
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core' ;

@Injectable()
export class Electron {
getRemote(): any { return electron.remote ; }
```

It is never called, though, only imported in app.module.ts. I created it just to see possible compilation errors.

As for the environment, I installed **typings** in devDependencies and then installed **dt~node** and **dt~electron** (in typings/global/electron/index.d.ts there is some problem in that **tsc** it does not recognize *Promise<any>* which I had to replace manually by *any* to make compilation of the electron main file possible).

As long as I do not want to use the electron API (`electron.remote`) everything works fine, with some minor quirks in angular, irrelevant to this topic. But as soon as I try to import electron, I get this strange error.

Any idea how to overcome this or where to look for the cause? Why one built-in nodejs module, path, is imported without problems but, in the same file, require() of another built-in module, fs, returns something that is not fs?

Versions (process.versions in the renderer process):

```
ares:"1.10.1-DEV"
atom-shell:"1.4.14"
chrome:"53.0.2785.143"
electron:"1.4.14"
http_parser:"2.7.0"
modules:"50"
node:"6.5.0"
openssl:"1.0.2h"
uv:"1.9.1"
v8:"5.3.332.47"
zlib:"1.2.8"
```

The NodeJS version where I run the compilation is 6.9.3 x64 Windows.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you figure out something?

Comment: @EdoB we just started some big project and I did not have much time to play with it.  However, I used a starter that works for different angular 2 configurations (dev server, prod server, electron app) and it works.  Did not check the `electron.remote` API yet. https://github.com/JonnyBGod/angular2-webpack-advance-starter

Comment: @EdoB tested and failed: same issue when I add `import remote from 'electron' ;` - obviously, there is some bug in the electron package that causes module resolver to fail on fs.

Comment: Also having the same problem. Has anyone figured out what the problem is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\` \_\_webpack\_require\_\_(...) is not a function\` when using babel 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683539/webpack-require-is-not-a-function-when-using-babel-6)

Answer (score 0):

As [@ccnokes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397311/ccnokes) pointed it out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43971252/4973023):

> Webpack brings its own require which clobbers node.js' require, so when you require a node.js core module that webpack can't resolve to one of your files or dependencies, it throws. (You can see in your stack trace that it includes **webpack_require**. That's because webpack rewrites all requires to **webpack_require** so that it uses it's own internal node.js-esque system). Webpack is built for the web/browsers so it doesn't play well with node out of the box.

I would suggest using [ngx-electron](https://github.com/ronisaha/ngx-electron) that appear to be somewhat not maintained (last commit was a year ago) but still works as a charm and will let you use a lot of Electron abilities in Angular (like in [this answer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45692172/4973023)).

You could also try [this workaround](http://electron.rocks/angular2-electron/) by [Vjekoslav Ratkajec](http://electron.rocks/author/vjekoslav/):

In your **index.html**

```
<script>  const electron = require('electron');  </script>
```

Then in any of your **Typescript files**:

```
declare const electron: any;
```

The downside is that you won't enjoy [Typescript support](https://electronjs.org/blog/typescript).

You also could use [webpack-target-electron-renderer](https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer) to tell wich require to import with electron or webpack but I haven't tried it or [this boilerplate](https://github.com/colinskow/angular-electron-dream-starter) if you want to start your project from scratch !

Hope it'll help