# Accessing filesystem in Angular 2 app using Electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, fs

I know that Angular 2 is run on a web browser, which does not have access to the file system.

However, I'm using Electron as my front-end, and also running the app via electron:

```
"build-electron": "ng build --base-href . && cp src/electron/* dist",
"electron": "npm run build-electron && electron dist"
```

Therefore, I run it with `npm run electron` which at the very end runs `electron dist`.

Since I'm running through `electron` and not `ng` I would think that I should be able to access the filesystem. However, when I do:

`import * as fs from 'fs'`

I get an error:

`ng:///AppModule/AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:5 ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_fs__.readFileSync is not a function(…)`

Similarly, when I try: `var fs = require('fs');`

I get:

`ng:///AppModule/AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:5 ERROR TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function`

This is the call resulting in the error:

`this.config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('../../CONFIG.ini', 'utf-8'))`

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it by:

1) Eject webpack: `ng eject`

2) Add `target: 'electron-renderer'` to the `module.exports` array inside `webpack.config.js`

3) Require remote, since we're in the `renderer`, but `fs` is only available in the `main process` ([Read more](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md)): `var remote = require('electron').remote;`

4) Require fs (this time using remotes implementation of require): `var fs = remote.require('fs');`

And now it works!

Comment: If you are using the [ngx-electron package](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron) you can skip steps 1-3 and just require it via the ElectronService.Remote.require() function

Comment: `ng eject` Appears to have been removed.

Answer (score 3):

I am using

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.7
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.4
```

I tried the `ng eject` method it didn't work in my case, it is disabled by default and will be removed completely in Angular 8.0

Error message: `The 'eject' command has been disabled and will be removed completely in 8.0.`

It worked for me by creating a file called `native.js` in the `src` folder and insert the following:

```
`window.fs = require('fs');
```

Add this file to the `angular-cli.json` scripts array:

```
"scripts": [
    "native.js"
]
```

Add the following lines to `polyfills.ts`:

```
`declare global {
    interface Window {
        fs: any;
    }
}`
```

After that you can access the filesystem with:

```
`window.fs.writeFileSync('sample.txt', 'my data');`
```

[credits](https://github.com/PKief/angular-cli-electron)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you build the application with Webpack.

You can expose all Node modules via the **externals** array in your webpack config.

```
module.exports = {
   "externals": {
      "electron": "require('electron')",
      "child_process": "require('child_process')",
      "fs": "require('fs')",
      "path": "require('path')",
      ...
   }
}
```

Since they are provided through the Webpack externals, one does not have to require them but use them with imports.

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
```

You can read more about this problem in [my article](http://www.matthiassommer.it/programming/exceptions/webpack-node-modules/).

Comment: Hi, I had to `ng eject` to get access to `webpack.config.js` - There is no `externals` array in `module.exports`. I have added it, with the 4 externals you have listed above (I removed the `...` of course). However, when I type fs or electron in to the console, I get `fs` | `electron` `is undefined`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but I also stumbled upon this problem recently. To the late comers, you can use ngx-fs

https://github.com/Inoverse/ngx-fs

Usage:

```
const fs = this._fsService.fs as any;
fs.readdir("\\", function (err, items) {
   if (err) {
      return;
   }
   for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     console.log(items[i]);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve it in an easier way:

1. Just download this project as start, the 'require'-s are already in the webpack.config.js file (along with the integration of angular, electron and so on):
   https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron
2. import 'fs' into home.ts (or into any other component) as mentioned by @Matthias Sommer above:

`import * as fs from 'fs'`

3. Use 'fs' :)