# Accessing filesystem in Angular 5, using electron

Tags: json, angular, electron, angular5

I'm building an simple stand-alone angular application in which u can submit information.
This information needs to be saved in a local JSON file that's in the asset folder. I know Angular runs in a web browser that's why I use electron to build it. The problem is that i can't figure out a way to edit the JSON files in angular 5 using electron (local).

I have tried the solutions mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689376/accessing-filesystem-in-angular-2-app-using-electron), But they didn't work for me, any other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having this problem for quite some time i finally figured out how to solve it:

you need to put this in script tags in your index.html

```
  var remote = require('electron').remote
  var fs = remote.require('fs');
```

and in every component you want to use it you need to declare it globally

```
declare var fs: any;
```

then you can use it!

was quite a struggel to figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Because it's just JSON data, might I suggest using localStorage instead? Then, you can do something like:

```
...// Code that creates the JSON object
var theJSONdata = jsonObj.stringify(); // conver the object to a string
window.localStorage.setItem('mysavedJSON', theJSONdata)
```

;

Later, when you need to load the JSON to edit it or read it, just use:

```
jsonObj = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('mysavedJSON');
```