# fs.existsSync is not a function error in Angular & Electron app

Tags: angular, web-applications, electron, desktop, fs

I'm developing an app with Electron and Angular 4. I want to show a dialog when I click a button to select a folder, but there is a problem with the electron API:

[image: FS error]
I've seen a lot of people with the same problem but I couldn't find a solution to fix this. I've tried to modify the angular-cli config by adding a script that requires the *fs* module but it fails too...

My component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { dialog } from 'electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-photos',
  templateUrl: './photos.component.html'
})
export class PhotosComponent implements OnInit {

  private path = '';
  private photos = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openFolderSelector() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openDirectory'] }, (filepaths) => {
      console.log(filepaths);
    });
  }
}
```

Has anybody made it work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I'm struggling with the same kind of error...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785295/fs-module-fails-when-integrating-electron-into-angular-project/50465430#50465430

Answer (score 0):

Try to import "dialog" like this ?

> const { dialog } = require('electron');

[Source](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md)